# pgfplots: bar chart | bar missing if value greater than xmax / ymax | symbolic y coords

Tags: pgfplots, bar-chart

- I have a `xbar chart` in `pgfplots` with `symbolic y coords`.
- **When the value of one of the bars is greater than `xmax` then the bar disappears**.
- I prepared an example with `xmax=10` and the bar called `E` is in one case `10=xmax` and in another case `11>xmax`.

---

```
\documentclass[border=5mm,tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xbar,
    symbolic y coords = {A,B,C,D,E},
    enlarge y limits = 0.15,
    ytick = data,
    width = 160mm,
    height = 90mm,
    xmin = 0,
    xmax = 10,
    title = {E = xmax},
    ]
\addplot coordinates {(1,A) (2,B) (3,C) (4,D) (10,E)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xbar,
    symbolic y coords = {A,B,C,D,E},
    enlarge y limits = 0.15,
    ytick = data,
    width = 160mm,
    height = 90mm,
    xmin = 0,
    xmax = 10,
    title = {E $>$ xmax},
    ]
\addplot coordinates {(1,A) (2,B) (3,C) (4,D) (11,E)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

---

[image]

Comment: Looks like a bug, doesn't it? And as such should probably be reported at SourceForge. Note that you don't need the `symbolic y coordinates` to see the problem, something like `\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xbar,
    xmax = 10,
    ]
\addplot coordinates {(1,1) (11,2)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}` is enough. Edit: same thing happens with `ybar`.

Comment: I confirm this being a bug which I reported to the [PGFPlots Tracker](https://sourceforge.net/p/pgfplots/bugs/163/). Good catch!

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I have trouble with my account at SourceForge at the moment (password not working). Luckily Stefan already took care of it.

Comment: Well, then I suppose we can close this then. I mean, bug reports are off-topic, you already know a workaround, and your question is really just a statement that something is wrong.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is essentially a bug report for `pgfplots`, which has now been posted at https://sourceforge.net/p/pgfplots/bugs/163/

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Yes. Maybe don't delete it so that others can find the question.

Comment: For the record: The bug is fixed in PGFPlots v1.15. For compatibility reasons you have to add `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}` (or higher) to make it work.